# @の有無について

Tags: ruby

(※当方プログラミングを勉強して約1ヶ月になる初心者です。)
質問をご覧いただきありがとうございます。
あるRuby入門書を勉強している中で不明点が生じたため、質問いたしました。
Rubyバージョンは ruby 2.6.5です。

不明点のあるコードは以下の通りです。

```
class Product
  attr_reader :name, :price

　def initialize(name, price)
    @name = name
    @price = price
  end

  def to_s
    "name: #{name}, price: #{price}"
  end
end

product = Product.new('A great movie', 1000)
product.to_s  #=> "name: A great movie, price: 1000"
```

以上のコードは継承が説明された章に書かれています。

私は、Productメソッドがto_sメソッドをオーバーライドしているのは理解しています。
しかし、to_sメソッドの中で行われている、
`"name: #{name}, price: #{price}"`
でなぜ引数がname,priceとなっているのでしょうか。@name,@priceではないのでしょうか。

色々調べてみたのですが、分かりませんでした。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/232460

Comment: この質問に関して、解決致しました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 解決した場合はコメントではなく、解決した方法を自分で回答を書いて承認してください。そうしないと、他の人はこの質問について解決済みなのか、また、どうやって解決したのかがわかりません。

Answer (score 2):

`attr_reader :name, :price`

とかくと name, price というメソッドが追加されて
デフォルトは @付きの変数の値を読みます

つまり

`attr_reader :name`

は

```
def name
  return @name
end
```

と同じことになります
なので @ なしでも値の取得ができます

ちなみに attr_accessor のほうがよく使うと思うんですが setter も一緒につくので

```
def name=(val)
 @name = val
end
```

もついてきます

[attr_reader (Module)](https://ref.xaio.jp/ruby/classes/module/attr_reader)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。解決いたしました。